# How to start an activity on tap of push notification,while app is closed (not even in background)

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

I am working on firebase push notifications in android,I have implemented it successfully,all is working well,I am launching a specific activity on push tap,Its working but only when my app is running in background,When app is closed(not in background) then tapping on push start the app from first activity(main activity).I have searched lot many links with no luck,So can any buddy help me to figure it out,I am posting my code here.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
    public static String PUSH_NOTIFICATION = "PUSH_NOTIFICATION";
    String store_id, img_url;
    String store_name;
    String headline;
    String store_img;
    int size = 200;
    String subtext;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        size = (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(300 * 200));
        Message message = new Message();
        message.obj = remoteMessage;
        handler.sendMessage(message);
        Intent pushNotification = new Intent(this.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);
    }


    private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
// TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
            Log.d(TAG, "=====push msg------by jigar--" + msg.toString());
            final RemoteMessage remoteMessage = (RemoteMessage) msg.obj;
            if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
                final JSONObject jsonObject;
                try {
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
                    Log.d(TAG, "tag: " + jsonObject.getString("store_id"));
                    Log.d(TAG, "message: " + jsonObject.getString("img_url"));
                    store_id = jsonObject.getString("store_id");
                    img_url = jsonObject.getString("img_url");
                    headline = jsonObject.getString("headline");
                    store_name = jsonObject.getString("store_name");
                    store_img = jsonObject.getString("store_image");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {

                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                            .load(img_url)
                            .asBitmap()
                            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                    resource.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                                    Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));

                                    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), decoded, store_id, remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
                                }
                            });
                } else {
                    sendNotification("", null, store_id, "");
                }
            }
        }
    };

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody, Bitmap bitmap, String storeId, String subtext) {
        Intent intent = null;
        intent = new Intent(this, ProductDescriptionActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("storeid",store_id);
        Const.STORE_ID = store_id;
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT|PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            Log.e("===BITMAP ", bitmap + "");
            NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle notyStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
            notyStyle.bigPicture(bitmap);
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                            R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                    .setContentTitle(headline).setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange))
                    .setContentText(store_name + "\n" + messageBody).setContentInfo(subtext)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setStyle(notyStyle);
        } else {
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                            R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                    .setContentTitle(headline)
                    .setContentText(messageBody)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        }
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Random r = new Random();
        notificationManager.notify(r.nextInt(80 - 65) + 65, mBuilder.build());
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");
        wl.acquire(6000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your manifest

Answer (score 0):

please add below attribute in your MainActivity tag in AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Comment: mainActivity or the activity which i want to launch?

Comment: This is not working,Nothing is changed .same as previous,,!!

Comment: you could change your pending intent like this.  
`PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, r.nextInt(80 - 65) + 65, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);`

Answer (score 0):

Using below code i can open my MainActivity.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Comment: Please check my quetion first.